# How to dynamically create templated classes with compile-time information?

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic, systemc

I am working on a small design with SystemC for a systolic array. For that I have implemented a templated shift register class where the data type and the delay are the templates. For every row of the array I need to attach a shift register with a different delay, e.g. the first row has no delay at all, the second one has one cylce delay, the third one has two cycles etc.
For this I have constructed a loop inside the constructor that initializes the shift registers. The constructor then looks like this:

```
template<unsigned int HEIGHT, unsigned int WIDTH>
class SystolicArray : public sc_module{
  sc_module shift_registers[HEIGHT];

  SC_CTOR(SystolicArray){
    for(int h = 1; h < HEIGHT; h++){
      shift_registers[h-1] = new ShiftRegister<type, h>
      //Do connections here...
    }
  }
};
```

Now the problem I am facing is that the compiler complains that I can't use *h* here in the way I did:

```
# Error: systolic_array.h(61): error: the value of ‘h’ is not usable in a constant expression
```

and I do understand why that is the case. But, all the information I need to construct this thing is available at compile time since it is all derived from the *HEIGHT* and *WIDTH* templates of the array.

Is there a smarter way to do this than what I have tried here? I am working with C++11 and can only use the synthesizable subset of SystemC.

Comment: Please  include the full error  message in the question.

Comment: What is H? You can't pass a variable to a template typed parameter.

Comment: @273K That should have been HEIGHT instead of just H

Answer (score 2):

You basically want "run this code with different values of `h` at compile time." Perfect for a template. You can do it with a pair of overloads like this:

```cpp
private:
  template<int h>
  void init(std::integral_constant<int, h>) {
    shift_registers[h-1] = new ShiftRegister<type, h>;
    // Do connections here...

    // Next iteration
    init(std::integral_constant<int, h+1>{});
  }

  void init(std::integral_constant<int, H>) {
    // end when h==H
  }
public:
  SC_CTOR(SystolicArray){
    init(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{});
  }
```

With some precautions or possibly written some other way if `H` can equal `0`.

Answer (score 0):

C++14 has [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (which can be reimplemented in C++11)

so, with [delagating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor), it becomes:

```
SC_CTOR(SystolicArray) : SC_CTOR(SystolicArray, std::make_index_sequence<HEIGHT>{})
{}

template <std::size_t... Is>
SC_CTOR(SystolicArray, std::index_sequence<Is...>) :
    shift_registers{new ShiftRegister<type, h + 1>...}
{
    // ...
}
```